# Não é possível renomear arquivos de recursos (layout) (o Android Studio 3.0 Beta 3 está instalado)

Tags: android, android-studio

O beta 3 não permite renomear arquivos de recursos, como arquivos de layout. Ele mostra a caixa de diálogo de renomeação, mas ao tentar aplicar alterações, lê a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Refactoring cannot be performed File .../myapplication/R.java is
>   read-only

[image: R.java is read-only]

Alguma idéia de como consertar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de erro eu geralmente consigo resolver limpando o projeto.
Vai no menu Build > Clean Project. Espera terminar, então tenta renomear novamente.

Comment: Já tentei limpar o projeto e o erro continua.
Também fiz os passos do Stackoverflow English (link abaixo do @Roman) e também não resolveu.

Comment: Pelo que vi no issuetracker tem bastante gente com esse problema, talvez algum bug com um update do Android Studio. Tenta abrir o projeto em uma versão estável do Android Studio e renomear. Não é a melhor solução, mas deve funcionar enquanto não arrumam o problema.

Answer (score -2):

It's already reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65079508
Corresponding SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879726/cant-rename-resource-layout-files-android-studio-3-0-beta-3-is-installed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. In case you haven't noticed, this is the SO Portuguese community. Please edit and translate your answer.